# How to zoom in and zoom out using GSAP in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gsap

When I scroll down to the section 1 content, it will slowly zoom in to reveal the section 2 content. When I scroll back up and leave the section 2 content, it will return to displaying the section 1 content. If I scroll up again, it will show the same behavior as described earlier.

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { gsap } from 'gsap';
    import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
    
    const SampleZoom () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        // Initialize gsap and ScrollTrigger
        gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    
        // Get the innerHeight
        const { innerHeight } = window;
    
        // Define the zoom-out animation
        gsap.from("#section1", {
          scale: 2, // Zoom out by scaling down
          opacity: 0, // Make it fade in
          scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: "#zoom-out",
            start: "top top", // Start the animation at the top of the element
            end: `+=${innerHeight * 0.5}`, // End the animation after scrolling down by 50% of the viewport height
            scrub: 1, // Add scrubbing effect
          }
        });
    
        // Define the zoom-in animation
        gsap.to("#section2", {
          scale: 1, // Zoom back in to normal size
          opacity: 1, // Make it fade in
          scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: "#zoom-in",
            start: "top top", // Start the animation at the top of the element
            end: `+=${innerHeight * 0.5}`, // End the animation after scrolling down by 50% of the viewport height
            scrub: 1, // Add scrubbing effect
          }
        });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div id="section1">
           <h2>ROBO</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="section2">
            Hello world. I am Chitti, The Robot .. Speed 1 THz .. Memory 1 zettabyte. I'll be back. Get ready folks!"
The most expensive movie made in India till date has finally released and has already broken all box office records. Enthiran! This is the same movie that was originally supposed to start in 1998 with Kamal Hassan playing the lead role, then with vikram in the early 2000 and went on to cast Shah Rukh Khan a couple of years back and finally released with Rajnikanth playing the lead role. I managed to watch the movie a week into its release and like a farewell note sent by an IT/ITES employee, I have mixed feeling.
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SampleZoom;
```

Please refer to the below [link](https://www.loom.com/share/2b05a10a5bc6488bb90973ec5cae203d); it contains exactly what I need for my requirement.

[my requirement video](https://www.loom.com/share/2b05a10a5bc6488bb90973ec5cae203d)

I have tried several methods, but I have been unable to find a solution to this problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: better if you can share a link so could be tested as well

Answer (score -1):

In order to implement the zooming effect creating a seamless transition between `section1` and `section2` based on scrolling, you could try chaining the animations and tweaking a few settings. Then, set the `HTML > section1` to be be the "zoom out" trigger this way it should fully cover the viewport, then `section2` will initially be hidden below `section1` and will zoom in and become visible as the user scrolls.

Set the Initial Styles of:

- section1 starts zoomed in with opacity 1.
- section2 starts zoomed out with opacity 0.

When defining your GSAP Animations as the user starts to scroll, `section1` should zoom out and fade. Then, After this animation is complete, the user will be viewing `section2`. Then as the user continues to scroll, `section2` should zoom in and fade in, becoming fully visible.

Here's an example for you to get an idea based on my explanation above:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

const SampleZoom = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const { innerHeight } = window;

    // Zoom-out animation for section1
    gsap.from("#section1", {
      scale: 2,
      opacity: 0,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#section1",
        start: "top top",
        end: `+=${innerHeight * 0.5}`,
        scrub: 1,
      }
    });

    // Zoom-in animation for section2
    gsap.from("#section2", {
      scale: 2,
      opacity: 0,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#section2",
        start: "top center",  // This will trigger the animation when section2 hits the middle of the viewport
        end: `+=${innerHeight}`,
        scrub: 1,
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="section1" style={{ height: '100vh', background: '#f4f4f4', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <h2>ROBO</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="section2" style={{ height: '100vh', background: '#e0e0e0', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: '20px' }}>
        Hello world...
        {/* Rest of the content */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SampleZoom;
```

This should ensure that the animation starts when `section1` is at the top `(top top)`, and it zooms out and fades as you scroll, the animation for section2 starts when the section hits the `center` of the viewport `(top center)`. Based on you're design requirements, you may need to tweak the start and end values or other properties as this code is a basic example implementation to get you started with the desired effect.